# How to keep a number saved after page refresh

Tags: javascript, php

As the title, I need to let the number can continue increase after refresh the webpage but now the number will reset after refresh the webpage. Anyone know how to solve it?

```
Here is the number

<form method="POST">
                <div style="background-color: white; display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap; justify-content: space-evenly; margin-bottom: 15px; border-radius: 5px;">
                    <p id= "num" style="color: yellow; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: -15px;" class="number_border">0</p>
                    <p id= "num9" name = "num1" style="color: yellow; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: -15px;" class="number_border">0</p>
                </div>
</form>
```

```
Here is the design of the number
<style type="text/css">
    .number_border{
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: red;
        width: 20px;
        height: 30px;
    }
</style>
```

```
Here is the function to let the number can increase by 1 every 0.5 second
<script>
    var number1 = 0;
    var number2 = 0;
    var el = document.getElementById('num1');
    var el1 = document.getElementById('num');

    function incrementSeconds() {
        if (number1 < 9){
            number1 += 1;
            el.innerText = number1;
        }else if (number2 < 9) {
            number1 = 0;
            el.innerText = number1;
            number2 += 1;
            el1.innerText = number2;
        }
    }

    var increase = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 500);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you `NOTE`: Your code stop counting when `num2 = 9`
Do not try this code snippet here, stack overflow disallow using `local storage`

```js
    var number1 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('number1')) || 0;
    var number2 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('number2')) || 0;

    var el = document.getElementById('num1');
    var el1 = document.getElementById('num');
    el1.innerText = number2;
    el.innerText = number1;
    function incrementSeconds() {
        if (number1 < 9) {
            number1 += 1;
            el.innerText = number1;
            localStorage.setItem('number1', number1);
        } else if (number2 < 9) {
            number1 = 0;
            el.innerText = number1;
            localStorage.setItem('number1', number1);

            number2 += 1;
            el1.innerText = number2;
            localStorage.setItem('number2', number2);
        }
    }

    var increase = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 500);
```

```css
    .number_border {
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: red;
        width: 20px;
        height: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<form method="POST">
    <div
        style="background-color: white; display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap; justify-content: space-evenly; margin-bottom: 15px; border-radius: 5px;">
        <p id="num1" style="color: yellow; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: -15px;" class="number_border">0</p>
        <p id="num" name="num1" style="color: yellow; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: -15px;" class="number_border">0
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to choose a way to save the variable to the browser. The most common way to do this it to use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), though you could also use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) (not recommended since it's very limiting), or [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) (super powerful but overkill for the simple task you need to do).

So for example (I haven't tested the below but it should work or be close to working, and shows you how to use `localStorage`:

```js
// Default to 0 if they haven't been set before
var number1 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('number1')) || 0;
var number2 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('number2')) || 0;

var el = document.getElementById('num1');
var el1 = document.getElementById('num');

function incrementSeconds() {
    if (number1 < 9) {
        number1 += 1;
        el.innerText = number1;
        localStorage.setItem('number1', number1);
    } else if (number2 < 9) {
        number1 = 0;
        el.innerText = number1;
        localStorage.setItem('number1', number1);

        number2 += 1;
        el1.innerText = number2;
        localStorage.setItem('number2', number2);
    }
}

var increase = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 500);
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but after I press refresh it will add 1 to number2.
For example:
Before Refresh: 0 2
After Refresh: 1 21 then the 21 will change to 0 and continue increase by 1

Comment: Your code is what is doing that. You might need to change your logic, I'm not sure exactly what you want to do. But you can see above how to use `localStorage` to save/read data across sessions (reloads)

Comment: My code is something like a set of number that will increase by 1 every 0.5 second and dont let the number being reset after refresh the webpage. Need to let the number continue increase by 1 after refresh the webpage

Comment: I edited my answer a little, I forgot that you need to call `parseInt` when getting the value from `localStorage` since it can only store data as strings. Thanks @Mohamed EL-Gendy for showing that in his answer

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of state management , we can use queryparams in url after hash, in which the count/number can be maintained post reload/refresh.